# CommandBars("Row").Controls("Delete").OnAction Not Working Anymore

Tags: vba, excel

Good Morning,

I have the following code to customize the right-click menu in excel.
It is stored in **"ThisWorkbook"**. **ArchiveRow** sub is stored in ***Module1.*** It was all working well at first, then it stopped working completely, and gives a Run-Time

> Error 5: Invalid Procedure Call or Argument.

One minute it's working, the other it's not. Any help is appreciated.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.CommandBars("Row").Reset
    Application.CommandBars("Column").Reset
    Application.CommandBars("Cell").Reset

    With Application.CommandBars("Row")
        .Controls("Delete").OnAction = "ArchiveRow"
        .Controls("Cut").Enabled = False
        .Controls("Hide").Enabled = False
        .Controls("Unhide").Enabled = False
        .Controls("Clear Contents").Enabled = False
        .Controls("Paste").Enabled = False
     End With

    With Application.CommandBars("Cell")
        .Controls("Delete").Enabled = False
        .Controls("Cut").Enabled = False
    End With

    With Application.CommandBars("Column")
        .Controls("Delete").Enabled = False
        .Controls("Cut").Enabled = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Following sub is called onaction. I dont think the problem is there.

```
Public Sub ArchiveRow()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("DeletedList").Rows("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.Delete
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Commenting out all codes starting with `.Controls("Delete")` will work.
It seems any reference to this button causes the error.

Comment: are you sure its called "OnAction"?

Comment: And i dont think ArchiveRow should be in quotations

Comment: Yes. It used to work. Even disabling or deleting the "Delete" button is now giving the same error.

Comment: @mo.h yes it should be. Otherwise it gives an error variable not defined.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Did it change? For me `.Controls("Delete...")` works (on Excel 2016).

Comment: What changed between "it's working" and "it's no longer working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the delete control using the ID 293

```
Application.CommandBars("Row").FindControl(ID:=293)
```

i.e. replace `.Controls("Delete")` with `.FindControl(ID:=293)` in your code.

[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213552) is a list with control IDs for Office 2000 for reference. So the ID should be compatible at least with Office 2000 to Office 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely The name of the button changes by itself. From "Delete" To "$Delete" to "$Delete...". So i just wrote the code to detect the name of the button before referencing it.